# Will buying a Windows phone 8 app allow me to get the Windows 8 app for "free"

Tags: apps

If I buy a Windows Phone 8 app and there is the same app for Windows 8 as well, will I be allowed to download the same app to this device (Surface/PC) too? Same goes for buying a W8 app and getting the WP8 app if it exists

Comment: Good question. I'm pretty sure you want to know if it's like the Apple AppStore hybrid apps for iPad and iPhone, right? Would like to know that, too.

Comment: Yes, something like that. If app A is available for WP8 as well as W8 it would be good if I don't have to buy it twice to use it. I mean if I use the same ID for both devices then it should work (I guess:)

Comment: Hopefully we'll find out when Windows Phone 8 devices become available in a few days.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the moment, if we look in our Windows phone Dev account and the W8 app Dev account you have no possibility to interconect the app versions targeting different devices. There are some rumours about that becoming available, but for now its not possible even if the app developer wanted so.

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate today, with the advent of Universal Apps.

Answer (score 4):

With Windows 8.1 and Windows Phone 8.1, Microsoft is introducing the concept of Universal Apps. A developer has to enable this feature for his apps, and then even in-app purchases can be shared between the desktop, tablet and phone (at some point probably even your Xbox).

A nice, detailed write-up can be found at [WPCentral](http://www.wpcentral.com/what-is-a-universal-windows-app).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Check for this icon in the app description, it means you can use the same app on both windows phone and windows 8, no need to purchase the same app twice

Comment: That means that there is another, equivalent app in the other store. It does not mean the other app will be "free" if you purchased this one.